Node.js - Folder created with fs.mkdirSync() has root as group owner, can't delete it via Plesk
I'm using the following Node.js code to create a folder:
The folder is created successfully, but I noticed that it has the group owner set to root. Because of this, I'm unable to delete the folder via Plesk.
When I create the folder using PHP, everything works as expected. The folder can be deleted via Plesk without any issues. However, when I create the folder using Node.js, I can't delete it from Plesk.
Why is the folder created with Node.js being owned by root group?
How can I make sure the folder created with Node.js has the correct permissions and ownership so that it can be managed via Plesk?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Create a folder named 'hello_nodejs'
const folderPath = path.join(__dirname, 'hello_nodejs');

if (!fs.existsSync(folderPath)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(folderPath);
    console.log('Folder successfully created.');
} else {
    console.log('Folder already exists.');
}

To compare, I wrote the same functionality in PHP:
<?php
$folderPath = __DIR__ . '/hello_php';

if (!file_exists($folderPath)) {
    mkdir($folderPath);
    echo 'Folder successfully created.';
} else {
    echo 'Folder already exists.';
}
?>


